# "Top Level" category for indexes in OPmac

Tags: plain-tex, opmac

Is there a way to create a "top level" index entry in OPmac without a page number?

I'd like it to look something like this:

```
figs
-- green 1
-- newtons 3
-- red 2
```

Notice, there is no page number after the word `figs` (in this example perhaps there are only references to the three specific fig types in the text).

My current solution is this:

```
\def\indexcat#1{\openref\wref\Xindex{{#1}{}}} % No Page Number entry
\indexcat{figs}
```

But I was thinking there might be a built-in way instead of manually writing to the reference file like this.

Here's a little MWE to play with if you'd like:

```
% Process twice to get the index
\input opmac
This is the first page which talks about \ii figs \ii figs/green green figs.
\vfil\eject
On this page we talk about everyone's love of \ii figs/red red figs which are delicious.
\vfil\eject
And finally we have \ii figs/newtons fig newtons, which frankly one wonders if that's real fig in there...
\vfil\eject
\nonum\sec Index

\makeindex

\bye
```

(Notice that I had to put the rather annoying lone `\ii figs` entry to even get a bare top level entry -- though with page number.  Try the MWE without `\ii figs` on the first line to see what I mean.)

Comment: I don't understand why your elegant solution isn't suitable. I'd define the same but with space as a separetor `\def\iin #1 {\openref\wref\Xindex{{#1}{}}}` (Insert to Index with No pages). User can declare all such words at beginning of the document (for example) `\iin figs \iin bannas \iin coconuts ` or somwhere in the place where the words are mentioned. I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As @wipet's comment (the author of OPmac) indicates, a reasonable solution, and one keeping in the spirit of OPmac itself is a slight modification of my initial attempt:

```
\def\iin #1 {\openref\wref\Xindex{{#1}{}}} % Insert to Index with no page number
\iin figs
```

Then, for every "top level" index item needed, `\iin ....` could be added (likely somewhere at the top of the document.)

(Notice the space after the `#1` in the definition -- this obviates the need for the curly brackets around the parameter as long as it doesn't contain spaces itself.)